# How to fix Intellij 15.0.6 freeze in mac os high sierra?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My computer just freezes after prolonged use of Intellij 15.0.6 , which forces me to restart my whole computer. Cannot even open "force quit application" window.

I have switched the default boot JDK for intellij as stated [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html)

Logs from User reports :

> Time Awake Since Boot: 33000 seconds Time Since Wake:       6300
>   seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        25  Java: Java2D Queue Flusher
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000001000fb000 Exception Note:
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Comment: 15.0.6 is about two years old, and likely not supported on the newest OS.

Comment: @cello how come i force my company to buy a license every year :)

Comment: because it helps you being more productive than using older software.

Comment: @forum.test17 This issue was fixed some time ago. Did you try the most recent JetBrains Runtime version? See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879.

Comment: Just buy your own license. It's damn cheap.

Comment: @CrazyCoder plugin seems to be incompatible with the intellij version 15.0.06, nevertheless , new mac os high sierra update 10.13.1 seems to fixed the problem,no freezes since 2 days.